# mapa <iframe> se sobrepõe a barra de opções

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei uma class para poder aplicar o CSS, já mudei o posicionamento de relative para absoluto e no entanto continua como está na foto. Preciso que a barra não se sobreponha ao mapa e que o mapa ocupe a largura toda da página.

Comment: edite sua pergunta e coloque o código do que você fez, para ajudar a visualizar o problema

Answer (score -2):

Utilize a propriedade [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) para alterar a ordem de empilhamento dos elementos. No caso do mapa que é um iframe, se houver só ele, você pode utilizar:

```
iframe{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Veja se o valor `1` é suficiente para sobrepor a barra (se não for, aumente). É preciso também definir as propriedades `top` e `left` (coloquei `0` em ambas para ficar no canto superior esquerdo).

Em relação ao `iframe` ocupar toda a largura da página, altere o valor do atributo `width` para `100%`.

```
<iframe src="ORIGEM" width="100%" ...>
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

header{
   height: 50px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
}

iframe{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>barra</header>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d6272.568233324809!2d-47.88493191352716!3d-15.805026517819782!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x683f464424289e16!2sSede+da+Pol%C3%ADcia+Federal!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1542564229938" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```